# Show Week Dates (Start and End) Instead of Week Number

Tags: tableau-api

Is there any way to show the start and end for each week ?
or is there any way to make the week start from 1
[image: Here is a screenshot of my problem]

Answer (score 2):

Try `DATETRUNC(‘week’, [Date]}` as a calculated field on the columns shelf. Make sure to treat it as a discrete dimension.

It appears that you are using DATEPART() instead of DATETRUNC()